# Why numbers getting reversed when formatted in RTL Arabic - Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arabic, right-to-left, prawn

I'm using `Prawn` gem in my Rails app to generate PDF reports.

I read the documentation for putting the text in Arabic with text_direction RTL in arabic.

But, issue is that numbers are getting reversed here.

I wanted `semester 1234` as `الفصل الدراسي 1234`,

but in my app the output is `الفصل الدراسي 4321`.

My two lines of code is here:

```
pdftable = Prawn::Document.new
pdftable.text(t('org.semester') + " " + @semester)
```

`@semester = '1234'` (The reason would be that it is being treated as a text/string, thus changes to RTL (reversed))

Anyway, Please help me to retain numbers in proper order without changing the RTL format.

Answer (score 2):

Without hacking too much you could use

```
@semester.to_s.reverse
```

So you reverse the string twice

Comment: A good option. but, why it is coming wrong with prawn PDF generation?

Comment: I wouldn't know, but I'm guessing is that everything is fed as string to Prawn and parsed as string, so RTL. I've used PRAWN a lot, but I never had to deal with RTL languages.

Comment: Will it work if the number is embedded inside a string like 'Semester_1234'?

Comment: You mean if it is a string? String is string so it will be reversed.